# MongoDB Morphia elemMatch API

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm trying to put this into morphia query :

```
db.woot.find({
    "bar.tables": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "tableId": {
                $in: [3,
                4]
            },
            "tab": {
                $gte: 20000
            }
        }
    }
})
```

So I have :

```
Query<Table> q
q.field("bar.table").hasThisElement()
```

And after this I don't know how to finish the query and still using FieldEnd which supports in(), gte() methods without writing whole query myself with BasicDBObjects.

Please help me transform above query to the nicest possible Morphia equivalent.

EDIT: bar.tables is an array so matching must be done with elemMatch or else it can match first condition from some element and the second condition from the other element, but only elements matching both conditions are valid.

Comment: Just to get this right: (`bar.table.tableId` must be either 3 or 4) and `bar.table.tab` must be greater than 20,00 — correct?

Comment: Yeah. But note it can also be any other operator or data. Query is build over API which specifies the operator and the data.

Answer (score 3):

Morhpia now has elemMatch so you can execute your original query.

```
Query<Example> tableQuery = mongoDatastore.createQuery(Example.class)
             .disableValidation()
             .field("tableId").hasAnyOf(Arrays.asList(3, 4))
             .field("tab").greaterThanOrEq(20000);
Query<Table> query = getCDB().getDatastore()
            .createQuery(Table.class)
            .field("bar.table").elemMatch(tableQuery);
```

Something along these lines should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Query<Table> query = mongoDataStore.find(Table.class)
  .field("bar.table.tableId").hasAnyOf(tableIdArrayList)
  .field("bar.table.tab").greaterThan(20000);
```

You'll probably need some custom query builder, where you can set some conditions and it will then put together the right query for you — at least that's our approach.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention very important thing.  bar.table should actually be bar.tables as it's an array. So you need to match element or else one element can satisfy the first condition and some other the second. But one element should satisfy both conditions to be valid result.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Morphia — you'll probably need to fall back to the Java driver and create a subdocument there, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29818539/573153

Comment: Yeah that is the backup plan. Was hoping to achieve it with Morphia though.